# INOI 2011 Question 2: IOI Training Camp 20xx (Python)

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

Can anyone help me with this question?
I need it's solution in python

We are well into the 21st century and school children are taught dynamic programming in class 4. The IOI training camp has degenerated into an endless sequence of tests, with negative marking. At the end of the camp, each student is evaluated based on the sum of the best contiguous segment (i.e., no gaps) of marks in the overall sequence of tests.

Students, however, have not changed much over the years and they have asked for some relaxation in the evaluation procedure. As a concession, the camp coordinators have agreed that students are allowed to drop upto a certain number of tests when calculating their best segment.

For instance, suppose that Lavanya is a student at the training camp and there have been ten tests, in which her marks are as follows.

Test 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Marks 6 -5 3 -7 6 -1 10 -8 -8 8

In this case, without being allowed to drop any tests, the best segment is tests 5–7, which yields a total of 15 marks. If Lavanya is allowed to drop upto 2 tests in a segment, the best segment is tests 1–7, which yields a total of 24 marks after dropping tests 2 and 4. If she is allowed to drop upto 6 tests in a segment, the best total is obtained by taking the entire list and dropping the 5 negative entries to get a total of 33.

You will be given a sequence of N test marks and a number K. You have to compute the sum of the best segment in the sequence when upto K marks may be dropped from the segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
# Read N and K
(N, K) = input().strip().split()
(N, K) = (int(N), int(K))
# Read Marks
marks = []
for i in range(N):
  x = int(input())
  marks.append(x)
#Let Best[i][j] denote the maximum segment ending at position i with at most j marks dropped.
Best = [[0 for i in range(K + 1)] for j in range(len(marks))] 
Best[0][0] = marks[0]
#Filling up Best[i][j] for j = 0, i.e 1 mark dropped.
for i in range(1, len(marks)):
  if marks[i] < (Best[i - 1][0] + marks[i]):
    Best[i][0] = Best[i - 1][0] + marks[i]
  else: 
    Best[i][0] = marks[i]
#Inductively filling the rest of the list(Best)
for j in range(1, K + 1):
  for i in range(len(marks)):
    Best[i][j] = max(Best[i - 1][j - 1], marks[i] + Best[i - 1][j], Best[i][j - 1])
#Finding the maximum
maxMarks = Best[0][K]
for i in range(len(marks)):
  if Best[i][K] > maxMarks:
    maxMarks = Best[i][K]
print(maxMarks)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Nstr,Kstr) = input().strip().split()
(N,K) = (int(Nstr),int(Kstr))

# Read marks

marks = [ 0 for i in range(N) ]
for i in range(N):
  marks[i] = int(input().strip())

# Initialize best

best = [ [ 0 for j in range(K+1) ] for i in range(N) ]

# Base case, incrementally track best answer
best[0][0] = marks[0]
ans = marks[0]

for j in range(1,K+1):
   best[0][j] = max(marks[0],0)
   ans = max(ans,best[0][j])

# Inductive case
for i in range(1,N):

  # Normal maximum segment
  best[i][0] = max(best[i-1][0],0)+marks[i]
  ans = max(ans,best[i][0])

  # Maximum segment with dropping
  for j in range(1,K+1):
    best[i][j] = max(best[i-1][j]+marks[i],best[i-1][j-1])
    ans = max(ans,best[i][j])

# Final answer
print(ans)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. If we add some explanation of your code, it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
N,K = list(map(int,input().split()))
final = [0]
output = 0
for i in range(N):
    final.    append(  int    (input()))
score = [[0 for i in range(K+1)] for j in range(N+1)]
for i in range(1, N+1):
    score[i][0] = max(score[i-1][0]+final[i], final[i])
    for j in range(1, min(i+1, K+1)):
        score[i][j] = max(score[i-1][j]+final[i], score[i-1][j-1])
for i in range(1, N+1):
    output = max(output, score[i][K])
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. If we add some explanation of your code, it will be better.